# Client Upload to Vercel Blob using Svelte

Tags: svelte, vercel

I am trying to replicate the next.js code to svelte

https://vercel.com/docs/storage/vercel-blob/using-blob-sdk#upload

It asks for giving a path to run a server side function which I don't know about implementing in svelte

> handleUploadUrl   Yes*    A string specifying the route to call for generating client tokens for client uploads.

Next.js Version

```
const newBlob = await upload(file.name, file, {
            access: 'public',
            handleUploadUrl: '/api/avatar/upload',
          });
```

Let me know how I can provide a url which exports a function to carry out

> onBeforeGenerateToken

> onUploadCompleted

I have my secret key as an environment variable.

I have tried to put a file in the routes directory, but I am getting an error which says path not found.